# How i can remove with AngularJs the browser cache before login request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, caching

I've created a login html login page with bootstrap and angularjs. I've remove bootstrap code to make html code cleaner. I have a UserController (Angular controller). In which i've implemented a submitCredentials function. Here is the html login page :

```
<div id="alertBox" data-ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">
            <button type="button" data-ng-click="error = null;" class="close">&times;</button>
            <strong>Oh no!&nbsp;</strong><span data-ng-bind="error"></span>
        </div>
<div ng-controller="UserController">
<h4>Login</h4>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name=loginForm" novalidate="novalidate">

      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" ng-model="credentials.email" required>


      <input type="password" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="credentials.password" ng-minlength=8 required>

      <button ng-click="submitCredentials(credentials)" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>

</form>
```

Here is my controller code:

```
$scope.submitCredentials = function(user) {
            UserService.authenticate(user)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.loading = false;
                var authToken = data.token;
                $rootScope.authToken = authToken;
                if(authToken){
                    $rootScope.authenticated=true;
                    $location.path('/');
                }
            })
            .error(function(data) {
        $rootScope.error = "Failed to login";
        $location.path('/users/login');
    });
```

The controller function works well. I use UserService angularjs service with make http call to Spring MVC backend. This work well.

The problem is about the alertBox in login form.

```
<div id="alertBox" data-ng-show="error" class="alert alert-danger">
                <button type="button" data-ng-click="error = null;" class="close">&times;</button>
                <strong>Oh no!&nbsp;</strong><span data-ng-bind="error"></span>
            </div>
```

This alert box is displayed when login failed. $rootScope.error value set. When i tried to login first time with bad credentials. The alertBox is display, then i close the alertBox with my button. When i tried again with bad credentials, the alertBox is not displayed for the second time. I have remove browser cache ( CTRL + F5) to display the alertBox when i sublit form with bad credentials. 
How i can remove with AngularJs the cache before login request ?

Comment: If you render error outside alert does it changes it's value on second login? Are you sure that rootScope inside login function is the same as scope inside view?

Comment: Assuming you haven't supplied your own [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory), you can clear the default HTTP cache Angular uses with `$cacheFactory.get('$http')`. If you have access to the backend implementation, you could try adding no cache headers to the responses too if you're worried caching is the problem.